# How to solve for the closed form of this recurrence?

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

For integers $L,k \geq 0$:

$$T(L,k) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if }k \geq d, \text{ever}\\
-a_{k} & \text{if }L=0 \text{ and } k<d\\
a_dT(L-1,k+1) - a_{k}T(L-1,0)& \text{if } L>0 \text{ and } k<d\\
\end{cases}$$

The $a_i$ numbers are all constants (from $a_0$, $a_1$, ..., $a_{d}$), so these terms are static and known.

I am having difficulty trying to parse this into something that is closed form (probably a combinatoric). Is this something Mathematica can do? I've tried RSolve but I don't think I was able to get the syntax right. I'm not even sure if this is *possible* in Mathematica.

Comment: I think you need to do this by hand for `L = 0`, then `L = 1`, etc., until you get enough of a feel for the problem that you can program it.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest that: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @djp I already tried that but was unable to get any of the syntax to work because I have a mix of different things at once. Piecewise conditionals, subscripted variables, etc.

Comment: Aruka I think that is your problem --- this isn't a problem of "how to program this in Mathematica" so much as "what is the problem in the first place".

Comment: @djp I know what the problem is fine. I don't know how to set up the syntax for it in Mathematica, though.

Comment: Certainly, Mathematica can solve this recurrence relation for any array `a` of constants and can solve it in closed form for many choices of `a`.  Please at least provide a typical array `a`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey The problem is that the array of $a$ can be any random array of integers for some arbitrary length. For example a=[5,8,1425,6,345,54658,3,8,24234,6,46546] etc. Does the $a$ array have to be defined or can Mathematica generalize it?

Comment: So, you want a closed form solution for arbitrary `a` and `d`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Although $d$ and $a$ are linked, since there are $(d+1)$ elements of a. $a_k$ denotes the $k$th element of $a$, and $0 \leq k \leq d$.

Comment: Possibly `RecurrenceTable` could help for this.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I had tried that, too

Comment: I don't think *Mathematica* (or any other CAS) will be able to obtain a general solution to your recurrence for any array $a$. In general, the methods of computer algebra are not well-suited to problems involving indeterminate arrays of indeterminate size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward implementation

```
T[{L_, k_}, d_, coeff_] /; k >= d := 0;
T[{0, k_}, d_, coeff_] := -coeff[[k + 1]];
T[{L_, k_}, d_, coeff_] /; L > 0 :=
  T[{L, k}, d, coeff] =
   coeff[[d + 1]] T[{L - 1, k + 1}, d, coeff] - coeff[[k + 1]] T[{L - 1, 0}, d, coeff]
```

Owing to constants (from $a_0$, $a_1$, ..., $a_{d})$, so the $a_k$ should be written as `-coeff[[k + 1]]`, here `coeff` is $(a_0$, $a_1$, ..., $a_{d})$

**Test**

```
T[{2, 2}, 3, {a0, a1, a2, a3}]
```

> $-a2 (a0^2 - a1 a3)$

```
T[{4, 2}, 3, {3, 5, 6, 4}]
```

> ```
> -411
> ```

Comment: Very nice answer, but not closed form.

Comment: @bbgodfrey, thks, I would like to know whether the `closed form` means that $T[L,k]$ owns a analytical expresstion.

Comment: That would be my interpretation.  Of course, there may well be no closed form solutions.